# iOS Survey Application

Tags: ios, swift, uistoryboard

I'm in the process of creating an iOS mutually exclusive survey application that asks users various questions regarding an ECG/EKG test. So far (see picture below) my application is designed using multiple storyboards connected by segues, but after seeing the redundancy in each of the storyboard's design and layout, I'm starting to suspect that I'm not approaching the problem in the correct manner. I'm new to iOS development so please excuse me if this seems like a trivial question but if each storyboard has the same design and layout, should there be only one storyboard? If so, how would I go about constructing the logic to dynamically create the questions and answers? Any suggestions are much appreciated.

[image]

Comment: A bit late:Using UICollectionView and Using Data from array can help you.

Answer (score 3):

EDIT:
I found a framework that can do exactly what you need: ResearchKit. One of its features can be used to build forms really easily and quickly. This is the best tutorial I could find on using it:
http://www.raywenderlich.com/104575/researchkit-tutorial-with-swift

It explains all of the features, so all you need to do is read about the setup and then head over to the section called "Text Choice Question," because that's the part about making multiple choice questions. It also has lots of other question formats that you can use as well. It should be pretty easy to use. Good luck on your project!

---

First off, I would just like to address some vocabulary. The storyboard is the actual file you are inside of. Each different square with the UI elements is called a `UIViewController`

Could you please explain what you are doing with your UIViewControllers or post a bigger picture? It's not very readable. But I'm guessing that you are creating a new ViewController for each question, is that correct? If that is what you are doing, then you are right, it is not the proper way to do it. What you should do is just have one ViewController, and change the questions and answers with code. So basically, as soon as someone answers your question, you would have some code run that changes the text and buttons to progress to the next question.

I still don't know exactly what you are doing in the ViewControllers, so I can't explain any further. If I am correct about what you are doing, tell me and I can delve in a little deeper on what you should do. If not, tell me what you are actually doing and I can address the problem again.

Comment: I'm sorry if my lingo wasn't correct - this is the very first iOS application that I'm trying to develop. But, yes, what you are describing is essentially what I'm trying to accomplish. The app is basically a mutually exclusive survey tool that, depending on the series of answers selected, leads to a potentially prognosis regarding the ECG/EKG test.

Comment: How would I go about changing the questions and answers with code?

Comment: No problem, I understand that you are still beginning to learn. An example of how you could do this is have a variable that contains the question number. As soon as an answer choice is pressed, run some code that adds 1 to the variable to move the question number up, and change all of the text  in the question and answer choices to the next question.

A good way to do this would be to store an array of strings ordered by the number. For example, if it was question number 5, you would set the question text to questions[4], since the 5th question has an index of 4 in the question array.

Comment: Could you possibly show me an example in code of what you mean? Also, how would I implement a back feature and a progress bar? I know iOS has these functionalities built in,  but I'm not sure how to go about implementing them into my application. Any ideas?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply! I think I found exactly what you need! You can ignore everything I said before, because I found a nice framework that does exactly what you need called ResearchKit. One of its features allows you to build forms really easily, and it's pretty easy to use. You should probably use this tutorial:
http://www.raywenderlich.com/104575/researchkit-tutorial-with-swift
You can skip over to the section called Text Choice Question, because that's what you need to make multiple choice questions.

Answer (score 1):

**Install and Use cocopods**. (very easy to learn and use, also mainly used).

1. if it is your first time use cocopods, open terminal
2. enter `$ sudo gem install cocoapods` command in terminal.
3. Open a terminal window, and type `$ cd` into your project directory.
4. Create a Podfile. This can be done by running `$ pod init`.
5. Open your Podfile.
6. running `$ pod install` it should display "Cocopods are successfully installed."

**After cocopods installed**, Use Questionnaire FrameWork [as shown here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Radkw.gif))

[GitHub Link](https://github.com/James201311/Questionnaire) Follow the Use steps

1. import Questionnaire
2. inherit your controller from `QuestionaireController`
3. override following three methods:

   - `func questionaire(_ questionaire: QuestionaireView, didClosedAt questionIndex: Int, answers: [Bool], _ closedButton: UIButton)`
   - `func questionaire(_ questionaire: QuestionaireView, didFinishedAt
     questionIndex: Int, answers: [Bool])`
   - `func questionaire(_ questionaire: QuestionaireView) -> [String]`
4. present the questionnaire view controller you just created!

**Hope this solved your problem.**

Comment: Hello, I've improve a bit your answer in the formatting, please have a look and improve yourself